# Plotting MATLAB data from arrays with several dimensions

Tags: arrays, matlab, plot, matlab-figure

Consider the three-dimensional arrays

```
A = rand(3,4,5);
B = rand(3,4,5);

plot(A(:,1,1),B(:,1,1))
plot(A(1,:,1),B(1,:,1))
```

This all works fine, however

```
>> plot(A(1,1,:),B(1,1,:))
Error using plot
Data may not have more than 2 dimension
```

Is there a quick way around this a way around this other than using `reshape()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use [`squeeze`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html) to remove singleton dimensions:

```
plot(squeeze(A(1,1,:)),squeeze(B(1,1,:)))
```

another option is to shift matrix dimensions using [`shiftdim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/shiftdim.html)

```
plot(shiftdim(A(1,1,:),1),shiftdim(B(1,1,:),1),'o')
```

Comment: Thanks natan, I was unaware of `squeeze()`.